# In intsafe.h of win32api, why is the code for unsigned representation of the absolute value of an integer so strange?

Tags: c++, c, integer, overflow

I'm not familiar with c/c++, but I know that this code takes the unsigned absolute value. It's strange why Microsoft coder has to +1 to the integer number, then negative it, and then +1. Why can't it just be it and then convert to unsigned integer?

```c
//intsafe.h
    if (llMultiplicand < 0)
    {
        //
        // Avoid negating the most negative number.
        //
        ullMultiplicand = ((ULONGLONG)(- (llMultiplicand + 1))) + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ullMultiplicand = (ULONGLONG)llMultiplicand;
    }
```

For example, for an integer with only 4 bits, the minimum value is -8, which is "1000" in binary. I know that the negative number is still `1000`, but if it is converted to an unsigned integer at this time, its unsigned absolute value can already be obtained.

I thought it might be a performance issue, but after running it directly in C language several times, I found it difficult to see the difference. And it is strange that the position of the function in the code will affect the overall time. For example, first write the abs1 function declaration and implementation above the abs2 function, or vice versa. The location of the call is the same, but the results are different. I can not understand

```c
unsigned int abs1(int x) {
    if (x < 0) {
        return (unsigned int)(-x);
    }
    return (unsigned int)x;
}
unsigned int abs2(int x) {
    if (x < 0) {
        return (unsigned int)(-(x + 1) + 1);
    }
    return (unsigned int)x;
}


int main() {
    int numIterations = 100000000;
    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;

    // Test abs1
    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++) {
        abs1(-5); // Replace -5 with your test input
    }
    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time taken by abs1: %f seconds\n", cpu_time_used);

    // Test abs2
    start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < numIterations; i++) {
        abs2(-5); // Replace -5 with your test input
    }
    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double)(end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time taken by abs2: %f seconds\n", cpu_time_used);

    return 0;
}
```

===============

Okay, I understand now that the fundamental reason is that many behaviors in the C/C++ standard are undefined. A sufficiently standardized library should not detect any undefined behavior, as the undefined behavior itself is undetectable. even if it has specific behaviors in certain implementations. I have also learned that some compilers will try to optimize these undefined behaviors, making them really unpredictable. This is different from many new languages ​​​​that are mainly implemented by the official.

===============

Comment: You can't negate the most negative number, because there's no corresponding positive number. E.g. 8 bit unsigned ranges from -128 to 127. If you try to negate -128, you get +128, which doesn't exist.

Comment: It's right in the comment:  `Avoid negating the most negative number`  That would be signed integer overflow and that's undefined behavior.

Comment: @Barmar That's a very good explanation, but I think you meant "8 bit **signed** ranges from -128 to 127"

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, and it's too late to edit now.

Comment: Is this a C question or a C++ question?

Comment: Okay, I probably understand. The root cause is that this is undefined behavior in the standard, although it is a definite behavior in some implementations. btw, I’m not sure whether this win32api belongs to c or c++.

Comment: The Win32 API is available to many languages.

Comment: The benchmarking code is too simplistic: with optimisations turned on, which is a must if you are trying to assess performance, both loops will compile to nothing because the code for `abs1` and `abs2` will be expanded inline, especially as the argument is constant, and discarded as you do not use the result, so the timings should be identical and vanishingly small.

Comment: @rwxe >although it is a definite behavior in some implementations
What do you mean with implementation? it is undefined behaviour in C++. The compiler can do what it wants. And for the actual hardware - there it depends on the instructionset and the actual hardware. CPU can for example use trap-values and overflow-flags, or just do it in modulo-arithmetic.

Comment: @ABaumstumpf Sorry, my English is not very good, I meant to say Specific Behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the `else` attempts to find the arithmetic negation of `llMultiplicand`.

`(unsigned long long int)-llMultiplicand` isn't used as it could result in undefined behaviour for the largest negative value.

---

Imagine if the `long long int` type was 8 bits long.<sup>[1]</sup> Its range on a two's complement machine<sup>[2]</sup> would be -128 to +127.  Trying to negate the largest negative value (-128) would result in an unrepresentable value (+128). This is an overflow. The same thing happens if `long long int` is larger.

Overflows from signed integer arithmetic are undefined behaviour.<sup>[3]</sup> The code is written as it is to avoid this undefined behaviour.

Let's go back to our example of negating -128 on a machine with a 8-bit `long long int`.

Naïve approach:

```c
  (unsigned long long int)-llMultiplicand
⇒ (unsigned long long int)-(-128ll)
⇒ XXX Undefined behaviour.
```

Approach taken:

```c
  ((unsigned long long int)(-(llMultiplicand + 1))) + 1
⇒ ((unsigned long long int)(-((-128ll) + 1))) + 1
⇒ ((unsigned long long int)(-(-127ll))) + 1
⇒ ((unsigned long long int)(127ll)) + 1
⇒ 127ull + 1
⇒ 128ull
```

Note that a good compiler will generate [a simple negation](https://godbolt.org/z/d1PbczPoa) for this code when the CPU provides a negation operator that provides the desired behaviour. So while it looks more complicated, there is no performance penalty.

---

1. It can't legally be that small, but I just want to work with manageable and familiar numbers.
2. Such as the x86 and the x86-64.
3. All unsigned integer arithmetic is performed with a modulo equal to one more than the largest number representable by the result type, so overflows aren't possible with unsigned integers.

Comment: The is a C answer. I make no claims that anything I said applies to C++. The question is tagged with both.

Comment: Okay, I probably understand. The root cause is that this is undefined behavior in the standard, although it is a definite behavior in some implementations. btw, I’m not sure whether this win32api belongs to c or c++.

Comment: Re "*definite behavior in some implementations*", No. You can't count on that. Undefined behaviour means the behaviour can change even from run to run. Or if you make any change to the file. Or if you look at it sideways. You're thinking of *implementation-defined behaviour*, which is something else.